# Inserting and updating disconnected entities in EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am retrieving data about books from lots of different sources such as XML and web services which I then store in the database using EF Code First 6 via a Generic Repository and and obviously DbContext.

The problem is that performance is very bad.

I have the following (fictional but analogous) POCO in my Model

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

also

```
public class BookDataSource
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual List<Book> Books {get; set;};
}
```

So I retrieve the book data from some source and construct the above book object.

I then need to check whether the book already exists in the DB and update it if it does or insert it if it does not. I also need to then delete any books that no longer exist on the data source.

//The following method takes the data source (type: IBookDataSource) to update from as the parameter

```
public string UpdateBooks(BookDatasource dataSource)
{
    string successMessage = "";

    //Disconnected entities
    List<Book> retreivedBooks= dataSource.RetreiveBooks();

    foreach (Book retreivedBook in retreivedBooks)
    {
        //Check if the dataSource already contains a book (based on title)
        Book localBook =
            dataSource.Books.SingleOrDefault(
                b => b.Title== retreivedBook.Title);

        if (localBook ==null)
        {
            //Insert a new one
            _unitOfWork.BookRepository.Insert(retreivedBook);
        }
        else
        {
            //Update existing
            localBook.Title= retreivedPortalMerchant.PortalsMerchantName;
            _unitOfWork.PortalMerchantRepository.Update(localPortalMerchant);
        }
    }

    //Soft delete any existing ones that no longer exist in the received data
    foreach (Book existingBook in dataSource.Books)
    {
        if (  !retreivedBooks.Exists(
                b => m.Title == existingBook.Title))
        {
            existingBook.Deleted = true;
            _unitOfWork.PortalMerchantRepository.Update(existingBook);
        }
    }
}
```

However the performance is very bad. Sometimes there are 25000 books retrieved from the data source and I am having to do two for loops. ForEach retreived book, check if one exists in the db the insert/update accordingly. And another one to loop all existing books and check whether it no longer exists on the datasource and soft delete.

Is there a better way to attach the entities and monitor their state. In the above example I think I am querying the context each time and not the DB so why such bad performance. Should I revert to T-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the proper algorithm of inserting-updating-deleting disconnected entities, you can check "*Setting the State of Entities in a Graph*" section of "*Chapter 4. Working with Disconnected Entities Including N-Tier Applications*" of "*Programming Entity Framework: DbContext by Julia Lerman, Rowan Miller*" book.

Also in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942176/362935) some ways to increase performance of EF is explained. The answer is for bulk inserting however it may work for your scenerio also.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way would be using [bulk insert extension](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/)

Here's [maxlego](https://stackoverflow.com/users/136399/maxlego)'s [description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23418092):

> It uses SqlBulkCopy and custom datareader to get max performance. As a result it is over 20 times faster than using regular insert or AddRange EntityFramework.BulkInsert vs EF AddRange
>
> ```
> context.BulkInsert(hugeAmountOfEntities);
> ```